# Unreal Engine5.1 Water System

Tags: plugins, unreal-engine5

could anywone help me, try to paint folliage on the `water body lake` but brush paints only landscape plane, but if i try to paint at `the water body river`, all works fine UE5.1. Me is newbee in ue plz dont hate me (:

Answer (score 1):

Landscapes are a "solid" mesh but water is simulated. If you tried painting on the water, UE wouldn't know where to put it.

If you wanted to have a floating flower on a water surface, it would be best if that water was a solid mesh with a water shader material, instead of a simulated body of water.

If you really needed floating "foliage" on a simulated water surface, you would have to create a blueprint and fix foliage mesh positions to simulated water surface positions, which might be too complex for a beginner.

Try placing foliage on a regular plane mesh, and apply a water shader to that plane. Ideally, you turn this combination into a blueprint. You can place these planes throughout your simulated body of water and match the shader styles so that it blends into the lake.

Answer (score 1):

there is an inbuilt buoyancy component in ue5.1.1(not sure if it's in ue4) you can add it to an actor blueprint and set the default root of the actor to the foliage mesh, add a pontoon to where you want it to float and it should work(it was broken in ue5.1.1 for me)